# How to add the ear JNDI namespace to EJB2.x Beans?

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, ejb-2.x, jboss-4.2.x

In the project I am currently working at we have about 20 different EJB 2 JARs that are used across multiple (Swing-) clients.

Example:

```
        customer-1.0.0.jar
          ^          ^
          |          |
   client-app-1    client-app-2
```

These different client applications have different release cycles so they usually need different versions of the same EJBs. Deploying those beans simultaneously does of course not work because they have the same JNDI name. As I am experienced with EJB 3 I thought deploying the EJB 2 beans in a per-application-EAR would solve the problem as the EAR JNDI namespace is used in EJB 3 beans (e.g. client-app-1/CustomerBean, client-app-2/CustomerBean, etc.). However this seems not to be the case for EJB 2.

Now, is there a way to prefix the EJB 2 JNDI names with the namespace of the EAR they are packaged in? I know that migrating those (legacy) beans to EJB 3 would be one answer, but we currently do not have the time to do this.

If the answer is dependent on the application server: We are using JBoss 4.2.3.GA.